# Does this symbol mean anything to do with heretics, or xenos in 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

We recently were given this symbol in our game of Dark Heresy as a clue in our murder investigation (was written in blood by the corpse):

[image]

So far it has not been tied to anything we have managed to uncover, but I recently stumbled across a bit of a joke meme, which used a similar symbol:

[image]

Ignoring the meme aspect, the 3rd, 4th, and 8th Legions have the same symbol, which are all heretical legions. The 10th (Iron Hands) and 19th (Ravenguard) are not a heretical legion, but the symbol is similar as well.

What does this symbol signify in 40k?

Comment: I don't think it means anything in 40k but that looks to be the Greek letter B (Beta)

Comment: It's a lowercase Beta. That meme is assigning Alpha, Beta, and Omega to the various primarchs.

Answer (score 4):

### Xenos

Doesn't look Eldar:

[image: Eldar Runes]

Neither T'au:

[image: T'au Alphabet]

Also not Ork

[image: Ork Glyphs]

Necrons doesn't fit:

[image: Necron Alphabet]

### Heretics

If this is considered a Greek Beta, there was an Alpha Legion Ship called Beta:

> The Beta was a battleship used by the Alpha Legion Adeptus Astartes in the years of the Great Crusade.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on the Beta](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Beta)

Otherwise, I wasn't able to find anything resembling this symbol related to heretics.

### General Symbols

There is also a great list of WH40K symbols from [Baka Design](https://bakadesign.dk/warhammer-40-000-icons/), where nothing resembles the one you're looking for.

### Conclusion

Doesn't look like your DM used a known symbol. But organizations / groups can use whatever symbol they want.